# Set up Emacs on Windows to start a single instance and open files in the existing instance

Tags: microsoft-windows

I am particularly interested in the full Windows experience including:

- Automatically starting a server if one is not already started
- How to call emacs so that it utilizes the server (e.g. from command line or third party tools)
- Context menu support (e.g. right-click on a file and allow it to be sent to emacs for viewing and editing)

Is such support available out of the box anywhere?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Automatically starting a server if one is not already started

This should be the same for any Emacs build. Add this snippet to your
`.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`.

```
(require 'server)
(unless (server-running-p)
  (server-start))
```

And then just start emacs by running the `runemacs.exe` executable that comes with the build.

> How to call emacs so that it utilizes the server (e.g. from command line or third party tools)

Emacs' Windows build comes with an `emacsclientw.exe` executable in the
`bin/` directory. Use the **full path** to that executable as your editor
of choice on any third party tools you need to configure.

> Context menu support (e.g. right-click on a file and allow it to be sent to emacs for viewing and editing)

1. Right click on a file, select `Open With -> Select Default Program`.
2. In the window that pops up, navigate to your `emacsclientw.exe` executable mentioned above and choose it.
3. If you don't want Emacs to be the default, do steps 1 and 2 again, choosing a different program as the default.

`emacsclientw.exe` will now always be an option in the context menu.

Comment: Thanks - great point about the server, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Regarding the emacsclient.exe, shouldn't that be emacsclientw.exe? Also, I thought you had to run this with the -a flag to specify an alternative editor if the server wasn't running.

Comment: In order to get the server to work properly with my configuration, I also had to add an environment variable `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` that pointed to my `.emacs.d\server` directory.

Comment: @Ryan I was able to get this working without the need for the environment variable - just needed to ensure that the server was running.

Comment: Hmm, for me evaluating `(server-running-p)` returns `:other` on Windows (even after trying setting that `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` env var.

Comment: **Update:** Got it working after `(setq server-use-tcp t) (defun server-ensure-safe-dir (dir) "Noop" t)` and setting `EMACS_SERVER_FILE` to point NOT to the directory but to the actual `server` file (For me that was `PATH\TO\.emacs.d\server\server`).

Answer (score 6):

> Automatically starting a server if one is not already started

I highly recommend setting an environment variable for `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` to `runemacs.exe`. This way you can always call emacsclient even if there is no server. Just add (server-start) to your init file. When a server does not exist emacsclient calls the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR` which is emacs in our case. Since emace starts up a server in the init file, any new calls to emacsclient will be instantaneous.

> How to call emacs so that it utilizes the server (e.g. from command line or third party tools)

Use `emacsclientw.exe -c -n "your_file"` to open your_file . The `-c` argument creates a new graphical frame and `-n` allows you to close the frame without losing server state. You can even call it without a filename to open the `*Scratch*` buffer. Works from a desktop shortcut also. Using `emacsclient.exe` (note the missing w) will pop up a command prompt for a few seconds everytime you call it.

> Adding to context menu

Emacswiki has a nice page on adding Emacs to the context menu [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ContextMenu). It involves editing the registry node `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` to add an action to open with emacs.

Comment: The option `-c` tells Emacs explicitly to create a new instance/window, which is not what the OP wanted. Using `emacsclientw.exe` without options works better.

Answer (score 5):

Others have answered the server part. Here is what I do, to get UNIX / GNU/Linux-like utilities such as `grep` and `diff`:

1. Install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) (one-time operation).
2. Load [`cygwin-mount.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/cygwin-mount.el).
3. Load [`setup-cygwin.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/setup-cygwin.el).

However, be aware that there are different versions of Cygwin. I use an older version (dunno which one - hard to tell, AFAICT). Dunno whether you will have problems with recent versions.

See also:

- [Emacs on Windows with Cygwin](http://www.emacswiki.org/NTEmacsWithCygwin)
- [Ediff on Windows](http://www.emacswiki.org/EdiffOnWThirtyTwo)

Comment: Note:  Do not use the cygwin EMACS.  Install the GNU build from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/

Comment: I do not recommend to install Cygwin, as there can be undesirable side-effects (like breaking other gnu windows ports like emacs, gcc, ...), for just having some gnu tools. Instead install [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net) ports. You can install the whole package or selected tools of your choice.

Comment: @Seki - Yes, Eli Zaretskii says the same thing as you.  All I can say is that I have had no problem (and I have serious doubts wrt your claim of it **breaking Emacs**). But (a) I am using an old Cygwin release and (b) I don't use most of the UNIX / GNU Linux utilities provided by Cygwin.

Comment: @drew: perhaps excessive for talking about "breaking" emacs, "causing weird behavior" would have been better. For example Cygwin Make will brake the MinGW toolchain if you do not carefully check your path for Cygwin tools not being taken into account or taken by default if no other exist. It is not limited to Make, many other tools cannot mix and sometimes it is subtle to point the problem. So in short, either you have a native port of Emacs and it is better to have native GNU tools, or you can use the whole Cygwin distribution including its emacs.

Comment: @Seki: So it seems that your main point is that Cygwin and MingGW do not play well together. That's not surprising to me. (FWIW, I have nothing against using MingGW instead of Cygwin. For me it was simple to install Cygwin, and I don't use enough of it to have encountered problems.)

Comment: @Drew: No, actually my point was that installing Cygwin for just having some Gnu command line tools is overkill when simpler and smaller solutions exist. GnuWin32 binaries are more "isolated" (you can just install one tool) when you just need, say, `grep` or `wget` while Cygwin must install a package of tools for at first initialize the Cygwin ecosystem. But Cygwin is useful, I do use it for specific tasks.

Comment: This answers the question in the original, overly-general, title, but does not help with the actual question.